# BASH search and print user, uid, last login

Tags: bash, awk, uid, passwd

With my rusty bash skills, I'm trying to do the following:

1. Find all users that have a UID > 500
2. Print list of users including their username, comments, shell etc
3. Append the last login date to each of these users

So far I have this:

```
[user1@test2 ~]$ sudo awk -F: '{if ($3 > 500) {system("lastlog -u" $1)} }' /etc/passwd | grep -iv username

    oracle                                     **Never logged in**
    user1      pts/0    hostname Tue Mar 31 16:18:42 +1300 2015
    user2                                    **Never logged in**
```

and this:

```
[user1@test2 ~]$ sudo awk -F: '{if ($3 > 500) {print $1 "," $3 "," $5}}' /etc/passwd

nfsnobody,65534,Anonymous NFS User
oracle,54321,
user1,54324,Test user1
```

I'm hoping to get everything  in one line like this:

```
oracle,54321,,**Never logged in**
user1,54324,Test user1,pts/0    hostname Tue Mar 31 16:18:42 +1300 2015
```

Not sure how to join both, and replace the space with commas.

Could someone advise? Thanks!

Comment: already tried that, doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
awk -F':' '$3 > 500 {("lastlog -u" $1 | getline a); print $1,$3,$5,a}' OFS=',' /etc/passwd
```

---

### Explanation:

- `$3 > 500` ensures UID (3rd column) is greater than 500
- `("lastlog -u" $1 | getline a)` to save the output to variable "a". This output should be equivalent to your `system("lastlog -u" $1)` -- I don't actually have this function, but I'm going to assume this works
- `print $1,$3,$5,a` will print what ever column you want (here I have column 1, 3, 5, and the previously saved "lastlog" output)
- `OFS=','` will use output field separators as commas

Comment: An attacker who can modify `/etc/passwd` has already won, so this isn't an issue in this particular use case -- but as a rule, using `system()` is dangerous; if this were reading an untrusted input file, content like `username$(rm -rf /)` would be honored. Unfortunate that gawk doesn't have any array-based exec() call.

Answer (score 1):

No need for awk here; bash can do everything needed built-in. (For the examples here, be sure that your scripts start with `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!/bin/sh`, or that you invoke them with `bash scriptname` rather than `sh scriptname`).

```
while IFS=: read -r username _ uid gid name homedir shell; do
  ((uid >= 500)) || continue
  { read; read; } < <(lastlog -u "$username")
  if [[ $REPLY = *"Never logged in"* ]]; then
    port=; from=; latest=
  else
    read _ port from latest <<<"$REPLY"
  fi
  echo "$username,$uid,$name,$homedir,$shell,$port,$from,$latest"
done < <(getent passwd)
```

---

By the way, saying that `join` "doesn't work" is most certainly wrong -- joining the output of only a single `lastlog` invocation is considerably more efficient than calling `lastlog` once per user, and can be done like so:

```
join -t, \
    <(getent passwd | tr : , | sort -t, -k1,1) \
    <(lastlog | sed -r -e 's/[*][*]Never logged in[*][*]//' \
                       -e 's@[[:space:]]+@,@g' | tail -n +2 | sort -t, -k1,1) \
  | awk -F, '$3 >= 500'
```

Comment: +for the `join` solution, but to make it robust (and slightly more efficient), you should add `-t, -k1,1` to both `sort` commands. I have  `avahi` and `avahi-autoipd` among the users, and the two sort differently with just `sort` vs. `sort -t, -k1,1`, due to the relative sort oder of `-` vs, `,` (locale is `en_US.UTF-8`).

Comment: @mklement0, thank you for the pointer; adjusted appropriately.